# Get data from database table by post_id to get data from second database table

Tags: wpdb

I have two db tables: wp_comments and wp_ratings. I'm trying to create a query using $wpdb which has to do the following:

from **wp_comments** I have to get the **comment_ID**'s where the **comment_post_ID** is equal to the current **post id** to get all the **ratings** from **wp_ratings** where **comment_id** is equal to the **comment_ID**'s i got from **wp_comments**.

wp_comments table is the standard wp table for comments.
wp_ratings is custom and looks like this:

wp_ratings:

- id
- date
- comment_id
- user_id
- rating

I'm struggling to determine wether to use JOIN or a subquery to achive this. I'm rather new to writing queries. So I only have a first part of a query so far:

```
$my_query = $wpdb -> get_results( "SELECT rating FROM wp_ratings WHERE comment_id =( SELECT comment_ID FROM comments WHERE comment_post_ID = " . the_ID () . " ) " );
```

I want the ratings to calculate (and show) the average value and to show the number of ratings.

EDIT: got the substringpart working:

```
$my_query = $wpdb -> get_results( "SELECT comment_ID FROM wp_comments WHERE comment_post_ID =  $post->ID" );
```

found a comment somwhere that when you use double quotes, you can insert a variable directly without closing the string!

Comment: Hey Bert, welcome to WordPress development. We need to see your current `$wpdb` call to be able to tell you what's wrong.

Comment: Since wp_ratings isn't a standard table I'd guess you'd have to write your own SQL query for this rather than trying to get WP_Query to construct one for you. (But maybe it's more flexible than I remember!) If you need our help writing the SQL, can you show us or point us to the schema for wp_ratings please?

Comment: updated my question

Comment: `WHERE comment_id =( SELECT` - you need `in`: `where comment_id in (`. I doubt it makes any difference to the database if you do a join or a subquery like this. It should be easy enough to get the count and average in separate queries if that's good enough, but you can probably do it in a single query with the right syntax. And depending how expensive these are you probably want to cache the results in transients, and / or compute a lot of these at once if that's more efficient.

Comment: @Rup: I discovered there is a mistake in the subquery. I ran the subquery as a query (deleted the outer part) which resulted in empty array. When I use the number of a post (that has ratings) instead of .  the_ID () . I get the proper results in the array. What should I use instead of  . the_ID() .  ?

Comment: Oh yeah, you want [`get_the_ID()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_id/). `the_ID()` will echo it to the output stream.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple things you need to do differently to make this work well.

1. Make sure you're setting `$wpdb` to the global.
2. Use `$wpdb->prefix` instead of hard-coding `wp_`.
3. [Wrap your variables in curly braces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35598187/when-to-wrap-curly-braces-around-a-variable).
4. Use `$wpdb` variables instead of table names, like `$wpdb->comments`.
5. Always always always use [`$wpdb->prepare()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb#Protect_Queries_Against_SQL_Injection_Attacks) before performing a query.

### Using `$wpdb->prepare()`

From the [Codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb#Protect_Queries_Against_SQL_Injection_Attacks):

> All data in SQL queries must be SQL-escaped before the SQL query is executed to prevent against SQL injection attacks. The prepare method performs this functionality for WordPress, which supports both a sprintf()-like and vsprintf()-like syntax.

[`sprintf`](https://www.php.net/sprintf) is called a bit different than most functions. Just like `array_merge()`, it takes as many arguments as you want to give it.

First, specify your SQL statement:

```
$wpdb->prepare( 
    "SELECT rating 
    FROM {$wpdb->prefix}ratings 
    WHERE comment_id = ( 
        SELECT comment_ID 
        FROM {$wpdb->comments} 
        WHERE comment_post_ID = %d 
    )", get_the_ID() )
```

Notice the `%d` in the prepare statement? This means you're expecting an integer here. If you don't get an integer from `get_the_ID()`, the process will error out to protect your data.

Next, you add in your expected parameters in the order they appear in the SQL statement. Since we only have one in this statement, we add `get_the_ID()` after the SQL statement.

## Putting it all together

```
global $wpdb;
$my_query = $wpdb->get_results( 
    $wpdb->prepare( 
        "SELECT rating 
        FROM {$wpdb->prefix}ratings 
        WHERE comment_id = ( 
            SELECT comment_ID 
            FROM {$wpdb->comments} 
            WHERE comment_post_ID = %d 
        )", 
    get_the_ID() ) 
);
```